# Android - add Layout views into ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter

the problems is, that I wan't to make ListView with elements which are containing image, description and two buttons. I'm making them in my own BaseAdapter extension, but fragment which is containing ListView is closing (wihtout errors in logcat..). I've found, that ListView is working well, when I'm not returning layout-type elements. So there is my sample with 'sample linear layout', which is not working.. Is there any possibility, to show layouts in ListView?

Here is my code:
Creating part:

```
lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.main_wall_ambajes_lv);
AmbajAdapter aa = new AmbajAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), StaticData.ambajes);
lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

My getView method from adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
    iv.setImageBitmap(placeholderBitmap);
    ll.addView(iv);
    ll.addView(iv);
    ll.addView(iv);
    ll.addView(iv);
    return ll;
}
```

Comment: use customized adapter extending base adapter

Comment: have your tried with LayoutInflater? is more easy

Comment: @Shrinithi I'm using it...

Comment: @ƒernandoValle put you on the right way. Create a layout designed for what you need then inflate it.

Comment: here is a good example: http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/

Comment: You can create a class that extends LinearLayout that represents a list item, and a layout xml. In the getView method, inflate the class with the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't have any error however I don't think you proceed the correct way.

Usually you create the layout in the xml file of the layout folder and only inflate it in the `getView()`, for example as follow :

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, parent, false);
    }

    //your code for setting the image or other things goes here
    //for example if you have a textView
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_textview_id);
    textView.setText("my custom text for this cell");

    return (view);
}
```

and `your_custom_layout` is simply the xml file of your layout.

**Note** that for performance reason due to cell recycling I only inflate the view when it is null and I only read once the `LayoutInflater` context and put it in `mInflater`. However for the best performance you should use a `ViewHolder`, but it is out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Thank you for advice. It's working now (I don't know, why it didn't work before, when I was making layout in code). Oh, and also code is much more clear now :-) Thank you one more time.